# Failed to apply gradle grails plugin after migrating Grails from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-3.0.9

My build.gradle file fails with below error after migrating from Grails 2.x to 3.x.

Failed to apply plugin [id 'grails']
Could not find method create() for arguments [main] on [Java source 'main:j
ava', JVM resources 'main:resources', Java source 'test:java', JVM resources 'te
st:resources'].

The apply plugin: 'grails' is defined within the subprojects task.

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
        classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.1'
    }
}

version = projectVersion

/* 
 * Subprojects configuration and its tasks
 */
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        }

    /*
     * Applying Plugins at subproject level
     */

    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
    apply plugin: 'grails'
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Stacktrace

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project
 'sample'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$
1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(Project
ScriptTarget.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:153)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.eva
luate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:491)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:89)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLa
uncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:123)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGra
dleLauncher.java:33)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:100)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:94)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to
 apply plugin [id 'grails']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultP
luginManager.java:160)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPlu
ginManager.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.appl
yType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.acce
ss$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.ru
n(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.exec
ute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPlu
ginAware.java:46)
        at build_76213vzvbmfxlviw96kj1e2w5$_run_closure2.doCall(C:\build.gradle:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedActi
on.java:67)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractPro
ject.java:827)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractPro
ject.java:832)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.subprojects(AbstractP
roject.java:815)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMeth
od(BeanDynamicObject.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObj
ect.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(Composite
DynamicObject.java:150)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:
79)
        at build_76213vzvbmfxlviw96kj1e2w5.run(C:\build.gradle:
58)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method
 create() for arguments [main] on [Java source 'main:java', JVM resources 'main:
resources', Java source 'test:java', JVM resources 'test:resources'].
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(
AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDy
namicObject.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(Composite
DynamicObject.java:175)
        at org.gradle.language.base.internal.DefaultProjectSourceSet_Decorated.i
nvokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator$1.execute(Grails
SourceSetConfigurator.groovy:36)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator$1.execute(Grails
SourceSetConfigurator.groovy)
        at org.gradle.listener.ActionBroadcast.execute(ActionBroadcast.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDo
mainObjectCollection.java:165)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDoma
inObjectCollection.java:159)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(Defaul
tNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(Abs
tractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(Abs
tractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate._
configure(NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDeleg
ate.java:73)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator$_createMainSourc
eSet_closure1.doCall(GrailsSourceSetConfigurator.groovy:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedActi
on.java:67)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(
AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(
AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer$configure$0.call(Unknown So
urce)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.internal.DefaultGrailsProject.sourceSets(Def
aultGrailsProject.groovy:68)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsProject$sourceSets.call(Unknown Source
)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator.createMainSource
Set(GrailsSourceSetConfigurator.groovy:58)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator$createMainSource
Set$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator.configure(Grails
SourceSetConfigurator.groovy:50)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsSourceSetConfigurator$configure.call(U
nknown Source)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsPlugin.configureSourceSets(GrailsPlugi
n.groovy:154)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsPlugin$configureSourceSets$0.callCurre
nt(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsPlugin.apply(GrailsPlugin.groovy:105)
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsPlugin.apply(GrailsPlugin.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyI
mperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImpera
tive(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultP
luginManager.java:144)
        ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing (or adding) your Maven repo to:

`maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/repo" }` (`repo` instead of `core`).

Comment: Added maven repo but still getting the same error. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

The apply plugin: 'grails' does not work with latest grails gradle plugin versions